(functional programming) What do you call a function that abstracts away a group of function calls?
(this question is written from a functional javascript point of view)
say you have some pure functions:
function a (arg) {
  ...
  return result
}

function b (arg) {
  ...
  return result
}

function c (arg) {
  ...
  return result
}

And in your business logic, you are looping through a list of data and processing each datum
for (const datum of data) {
  const { preA, preB, preC } = datum

  const postA = a(preA)
  const postB = b(preB)
  const postC = c(preC)
  ...
}

Say that it's not just three function calls in this for loop, but dozens, and you want to encapsulate this set of functions into some outer function:
function outerFunction(datum) {
  const { preA, preB, preC } = datum

  const postA = a(preA)
  const postB = b(preB)
  const postC = c(preC)
  ...

  return {
    postA,
    postB,
    postC,
    ...
  }
}

And your business logic now looks like:
for (const datum of data) {
  const { postA, postB, postC, ... } = outerFunction(datum)
  ... 
}

How would you describe this outer function?
facade function?
wrapper function?
helper function?
orchestrator function?
Would you call it something else? Would you approach this code in a different way?

It doesn't really change the question, but a pure functional style would use a map function rather than iteration.

I would try to avoid naming functions like this based on their structure and try to name them based on the actual real-world functionality/behaviour they represent,
using terminology from your real-world business/problem domain as far as possible.     It can often be very hard for people to understand code where names are based on "what it is".    (A good reason to avoid such names -- e.g. if you are thinking of naming something a "handler" or "wrapper" or "manager" or "orchestrator" then it generally won't help future developers as it doesn't tell them anything useful)

@BenCottrell yeah this is a really contrived example. In real life, I would not name this function "outerFunction", if that's what you're referring to. I am more wondering what "type" of function it is. The real life function is called getMemberFields because that is what it is doing.

Each of the smaller functions is responsible for getting one (or a related group of) fields, and the outer function encapsulates all of that logic.
In reality, this code is roughly a year old and has been edited a variety of times, so a lot of this logic was not created all at once. I'm trying to rework it in a way that's more readable, and trying to make it more "functional" as best I can

maybe all of the smaller functions should really be one function if that function is pure (even if it's a much larger function)

@PhilipKendall I didn't realize avoiding flow control statements was important to functional programming. Thanks. I need to do some reading

@rpivovar It's not about avoiding flow control statements per se, it's about avoiding (exposed) mutable state: in for (const datum of data) { ... }, datum is not constant as it changes value every iteration through the loop.

In a functional style, it'd be data.map(outerFunction).reduce(somethingElse) (or something more specific than reduce)

I would call it a function (like everything else in FP).

Doc Brown has a point there. On the one hand, yes, this is a kind of a wrapper function, but really, all you do when writing a program is you're calling functions inside other functions, and composing functions (and calling the composition inside other functions) - you distribute the responsibilities across various levels and you give each function an appropriate, descriptive name. You're not doing something particularly unusual. It's fine to discuss what kind of function it is, but I'd be more concerned about giving it a descriptive name that makes business logic read better.

P.S. By "descriptive" I mean something that has meaning within your domain. For example, "transform" (or "technicalTermTransform") doesn't seem that descriptive, but it's fine if in your domain it means a very specific thing, that will be immediately obvious to you (and your colleges, and other domain experts). Readability for anyone outside that "target audience" is not that important.

It's a compound function. Like the compound statement wraps code up in curly braces or begin-end, a compound function wraps it up in a function.

I would call it Bob. Assuming Bob made sense in your domain.
As for how to describe this implementation, I wouldn’t mind seeing it described as an Aggregating Function.
I hesitate to describe it as an orchestrator only because it’s just retrieving values. But technically it is an orchestrator as well. Just a boring one.
Always remember, name things after why you would call them. Not what they do. What they do is none of the callers business.

Have to disagree. "Fred" is much more descriptive.
